# How do I add a Qr Code to the POS Receipt in Odoo 16?

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo, odoo-16

I am working on a project where I am trying to generate a QR code based on the information of an order and output it onto a POS receipt. I have generated a QR code and saved it into a custom field in the POS order module using this code:

```py
from odoo import models, fields, api
import logging
try:
    import qrcode
except ImportError:
    qrcode = None
try:
    import base64
except ImportError:
    base64 = None
from io import BytesIO

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class PosOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = "pos.order"
    revenue_counter = fields.Float()
    qr_code_image = fields.Binary()
    qr_code_value = fields.Text()

    @api.model
    def action_pos_order_paid(self):
        _logger.error("It has been paid")
        res = super(PosOrder, self).action_pos_order_paid()
        _logger.error("It has been paid 2")

        if qrcode and base64:
            qr = qrcode.QRCode(
                version=1,
                error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
                box_size=3,
                border=4,
            )
            qr.add_data("Hello -- Test")
            qr.make(fit=True)
            img = qr.make_image()

            _logger.error("Image was created")

            temp = BytesIO()

            _logger.error("Temp was created")

            img.save(temp, format="PNG")
            img.save("Qr-Code.png")
            _logger.error("Temp was initialized: ")
            _logger.error("Temp was initialized: %r ", temp.getvalue())

            qr_image = base64.b64encode(temp.getvalue())
            _logger.error("QR-Code binary was created: %r ", qr_image)

            self.qr_code_value = qr_image
            self.qr_code_image = qr_image

        return res

    @api.model
    def _order_fields(self, ui_order):
        order_values = super(PosOrder, self)._order_fields(ui_order)

        order_values['qr_code_image'] = ui_order.get('qr_code_image')
        order_values['qr_code_value'] = ui_order.get('qr_code_value')

        return order_values
```

I have also modified the receipt using this XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t t-name="OrderReceipt" t-inherit="point_of_sale.OrderReceipt" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
    <xpath expr="//div[@t-if='receipt.pos_qr_code']" position="replace">
        <div>
            <br /><br />
                <div class="pos-receipt-order-data">
                    Scan me to request an invoice for your purchase.
                </div>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</t>
```

The problem is that I am not able to make the custom QR code field available in the view. How can I make the custom QR code fields available in the view, and is this approach of mine even the right one?